# Dropboxフォルダに保存したEclipseのプロジェクトが他のPCから開けない

Tags: eclipse, debian, dropbox

Debian stretch にDropBoxをインストールし、C++のソースコードを編集しようとしています。
他のIDEでは、問題ないんですが、DropBoxフォルダ内に、Eclipse3.8で作成したプロジェクトを、他のPCで開こうとするとプロジェクトを見つけることができません。
WorkSpaceディレクトリ内の、.metadata当たりが原因なのこと思うのですが、

解決方法は、無いでしょうか？

Comment: それぞれのPCはOSの種類やフォルダ構成も同じですか？

Comment: はい、同じDebian stretchです。フォルダ構成は、DropBox提供のLinux向けアプリをインストールし、dropbox startコマンドで同期後に開いていますので、同じはずなんですが

Comment: 英語版SOに類似質問があり、その中の一つに「Dropboxの[選択型同期](https://www.dropbox.com/ja/help/syncing-uploads/selective-sync-overview)で`.metadata`を除外してみて」という回答があります。 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6883280/2322778

Comment: 有益な情報をありがとうございました。